# Open iPhone/iPad settings from my app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

In my app I have some settings that are accessible within the Setting native app... a normal `Settings.bundle` file.

The question is "is possible from my application open Settings app to the settings page of my app to facilitate the user experience?"

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer no. There used to be URL schemes for iOS settings, but they got removed

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realise this wasn't possible as the other answers/comments indicate. But I've been using [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com) to mimic that behaviour anyway.

It reads from your `Settings.bundle` and creates a view controller based on the information.

[image]